# Click on RelativeLayout not Open the DatePicker DialogBox in android?

Tags: android, datepicker

I want to open DatePicker Dialogbox when Click on RelativeLayout(DateLayout). for I have done this. whenever Click on EditText and ImageView then also Open DatePicker Dialogbox Because EditText and ImageView Both are Including in RelativeLayout but Click on EditText and ImageView then not open the Dialogbox. Please Guide me. What Mistake in My code?

Thanks in advance.

My code is,

```
DateLayout= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.DateLayout);    
DateLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                datePickerDialog(); 
            }
        });

 xml file,
 <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/DateLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtStartDate"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:hint="strat date"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" >
                </EditText>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgStartDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edtStartDate"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/date" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clickable` and `enabled` of your `EditText` and `ImageView` should have be true.

Comment: EditText must be set the enabled false because can not change the date manually in EditText.

Comment: you can use TextView with custom style instead of EditText and then set an empty onclickListener to ImageView and TextView

Comment: What meaning of  set an empty onclickListener to ImageView and TextView?

Comment: can you send me demo? Please.

Comment: imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
  });

Comment: Thank you, I have Got Solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the EditText is consuming the touch. You can work around this by creating a custom `RelativeLayout` in which your override `onInterceptTouch` and put in some logic for when to pass the touch event to the EditText versus the RelativeLayout. It might be simpler though, and clearer to the end user, to just include a button in the layout to trigger the `DatePicker`.